# SQL/HIVE - Distinct count query - How does SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT columns,..) differ from SELECT COUNT(*) with subquery of DISTINCT records

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

In HIVE, I tried getting the count of distinct rows in 2 methods,

1. `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table);`
2. `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT columns) FROM table;`

Both are yielding **DIFFERENT RESULTS**. 
The count for the first query is greater than the second query.
How are they working differently?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Hive are you using?  Are you using Impala?  And, how different are the results?

Comment: Your first command gives me ParseException in Hive. Should it end with "as temp_table_name" ?

Answer (score 4):

Do a slight change to your query, ie name your sub query for eg:

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table) myquery;
```

Comment: An explanation along with code formatting will make your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in `hive`:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT nvl(columns,'NA')) FROM table;
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT coalesce(columns,'NA')) FROM table;
```

Above query output will be same as below:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table);
```